# Regex to check for repetition

Tags: regex

I need to check a string that must match:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7

So the rules are: only one number between 1 and 7, a comma separator, but I don't want repetition, so it's not legal to write:

1,2,3,1,5

Currently I'm using:

```
([1-7]{1},){1,6}([1-7]{1})
```

How can I modify it in order to check for repetition?

Comment: Why do you want do use regex for this? I think regex would be possible, but have O(N^2) complexity. Just use a loop and a set of seen values.

Comment: Because I want a strict check on user input.

Comment: Regex doesn't really do evaluation very well.  Split and check the resulting array for duplicates if you can.  Otherwise you need negative look arounds for each capture group and a very messy regex.

Comment: This is not a good use of regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878241/regex-to-check-for-repetition/33879327#33878496) is on the right track by suggesting that it's a good strategy to check for strings that *have* repetition, but I think you can have a more comprehensive regular expression that limits the character class and delimiter as you require.

**Update:**
This version checks for occurrence of multiple digits.

<del>`([1-7]{1})(?:[1-7,])*\1|[^1-7,]+`</del>
[`([1-7]{1}),(?:[1-7]{1},)*(?:\1|[^1-7,]|(?:[1-7]{2,}))`](http://regexr.com/3cb26)

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7    // PASS: no match
1,2,3,4,5,6,8    // FAIL: matches out-of-bounds digit '8'
1,2,3,four,5,6,7 // FAIL: matches non-integer 'four'
1,2,3,1,5        // FAIL: matches repeating digit '1'
1,2,3,45         // FAIL: matches multiple digits
```

[image: Syntax diagram via regexper.com]

Comment: It seems this expression no matches with 1,2,3,45

Comment: @greywolf82 Good catch. I have updated the RegEx to now check for the occurrence of multiple digit values. This was a bit tricky to attain, but the use of a syntax diagram generator greatly helped. I have included the generated diagram with a link back to the generator Regexper.com.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\1` to refer to a formerly matched group (the first group in this case). Use this to find strings that *have* repetition.

The regex could look like this: `.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b`

- `.*` anything
- `\b(\d+)\b` number between word delimiters (group 1)
- `.*` more anything
- `\b\1\b` group 1 again between word delimiters

Example in Python:

```
>>> p = r".*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b"
>>> re.match(p, "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")
None
>>> re.match(p, "1,2,3,1,5")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x8d2c2a0>
```

This will not check for those comma separators, though, so you'd have to do this in two steps: First check the general layout, then filter out those with repetitions.

Note, however, that the performance of this will probably not be good: It has to try each number for the first group, then match the string to see if there is another group that is the same as the first, then backtrack and try again, giving this O(n²) complexity. Instead, I suggest just using a set of already seen numbers and a loop.

Comment: This works backwards by matching the offending strings instead of matching the correct strings. It also doesn't account for the OP's other rule: "only one number between 1 and 7" so, this passes: `1,2,3,4,5,6,8` And because it uses the "any character" `.` (dot), this passes: `1,2,3,four,5,6,7`.

Comment: @gfullam Yes, that's why I said to use this to find string that _have_ repetitions and pointed out that he will need another regex for checking the general layout.

Comment: You're right that it's a good strategy to check for strings that *have* repetition, but I feel like this still falls a bit short. I don't think you need a second pass either. A more comprehensive regex is possible.

Comment: @gfullam Yes, a more comprehensive regex is probably possible. But the question is: Is a regex, that does all those checks are one, still understandable? Sometimes it's better to do one problem at a time instead of trying  everything at once.